# error C2864: 'element::next' : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class (STRUCT)

Tags: c++, struct

I'm having an issue with VisualStudio c++ compiler. While making a struct:

```
struct element{
element* next=NULL;
element* prev=NULL;
char value;
};
```

the compiler shows an error

> main.cpp(21) : error C2864: 'element::next' : only static const          integral data members can be initialized within a class
>
> main.cpp(22) : error C2864: 'element::prev' : only static const   integral data members can be initialized within a class

On LLVM everything runs fine. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  Is it in C++11/14/17 mode?

Comment: I'm sending it on my online academic compiler. All I know is that it is working on VS compiler. I'm not able to check its version :/

Comment: Perhaps this topic from MSDN can help out? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acxkb76w.aspx

Comment: Topic on MSDN shows the problem with static integers. Mine are not static.

Comment: I would just add a constructor for element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you can change the version of the c++ standard being used msvc is going to use the older behavior of not being able to use inline initialization, you will need a default ctor. And because of MSVC debug build behavior you will likely need to explicitly initialize those members to null. (In debug builds MSVC default initializes many items to non-zero values).

```
struct element{
  element* next;
  element* prev;

  element{()
    : next(), prev()
  {}
};
```

Comment: Thank a lot! that was an issue!

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler version accepts it, you can use the initializer list within a constructor instead.

```
element():next(NULL),prev(NULL) {};
```

Your code in this case:

```
struct element{

    element* next;
    element* prev;

    element():next(NULL),prev(NULL) {};

int value;
};
```

also you can try using **`nullptr`** instead of **`NULL`**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use an obsolete C++ compiler. Use one newer: for g++ and clang++ specify `std=c++14` or `std=c++17`. For Visual C++ specify `/std:c++14` or `/std:c++latest`. I think you can set this compiler option for your online academic compiler.

Also avoid using `NULL`. Use `nullptr` instead.